# How to display an image as application badge on iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, notifications, badge

On this page it says:

Additional Information
Applications can offer up to three types of push notifications:

- Sounds: Plays an audible alert
- Alerts: Displays an alert on the screen
- Badges: Displays an image/number on the application icon

Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3576

How do we do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that information in confusing on Apple's part, but you can't use an image as a badge. The red badge circle with the number is what they are referring to as the "image".